# Undefined variable "images" or class "images.internal.imapplymatrixc"

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am using MATLAB 2014b and tried these commands:

```
RGB = imread('peppers.png');
imshow(RGB)
I = rgb2gray(RGB);
```

But I get this error:

```
Undefined variable "images" or class "images.internal.imapplymatrixc".

Error in images.internal.imapplymatrixAlgo (line 91)
Z = images.internal.imapplymatrixc(I, multiplier', constants, outputClass);

Error in rgb2gray (line 64)
    I = images.internal.imapplymatrixAlgo(coef, X, class(X));
```

Any idea?

Comment: Check out this MathWorks thread: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/337673 - Apparently this happens when you upgrade to R2014b.  The eventual solution was to follow the instructions on this answer: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94040-why-do-i-receive-the-warning-message-warning-name-is-nonexistent-or-not-a-directory-when-i

Comment: Unfortunately non of those methods did resolve my problem!

Comment: My apologies!  You may have to contact MathWorks because I'm out of options.  BTW, you can calculate `rgb2gray` yourself by doing: `I = uint8(sum(bsxfun(@times, double(RGB), permute(1/3*ones(3,1), [3 2 1])), 3));`

Comment: @rayryeng the coefficients of each channel are not the same when converting to gray. The right weights are `[0.299 0.587 0.114]`. See [`rgb2ntsc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/rgb2ntsc.html) for details.

Comment: @Shai yes those are the right weights. Couldn't remember what they were.... Wrote that code on mobile. FWIW, that's how `rgb2gray` used to work before adopting the SMPTE standard.

Comment: It does not resolve the problem, do you have any other idea?

Comment: If the coefficients given by @Shai are correct, then `uint8(round(sum(bsxfun(@times, double(RGB), permute([0.299 0.587 0.114], [1 3 2])), 3)))` should do the trick. Couldn't test this on 2014a though.

Comment: Could you check this location of your install? If its missing, chances are the installation is incomplete: >> which -all images.internal.imapplymatrixAlgo
<installation>/matlab/toolbox/matlab/images/+images/+internal/imapplymatrixAlgo.m  % static method or package function

Comment: I get this: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\matlab\images\+images\+internal\imapplymatrixAlgo.m  % static method or package function